# Modifty GridView::Widget content Yii

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I'm trying to modify a field of the GridView that I obtained following the Gii tutorial on the Yii framework website.

[GII PAGE](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-gii)

I'm not satisfied on how the population field looks, so I'm trying to convert it with some separators.

This is the index.php of the Country View

```
  <?=
    GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'code',
            'name',
            [
                'label' => 'Population',
                'value' => 'population',
            /* 'value' => Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal((integer)population) */
            /*  'value' => Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal($model->population) */
            /* 'value' =>  Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal('population') */
            /*'value' => Yii::$app()->format->number('population')*/
            ],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]);
    ?>
```

I don't know why in the CountryModel the population field is listed as integer:

`['population'], 'integer'`

And then when I try to convert it in the view I have some problems because 'population' is basically a String.

I commented out some of my attempts.

Comment: `I don't know why in the CountryModel the population field is listed as integer` because we can not count half of the person :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`yii\i18n\Formatter`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter)

Go to your `common\config\main.php` if you are using **`app-advanced`** or the `app/config/main.php` if **`app-basic`** and add the following under `components` array.

```
'formatter' => [
     'thousandSeparator' => ',',
],
```

Now you can format any given number like below

```
<?=
    GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'code',
            'name',
            [
                'attribute' => 'population',
                'label' => 'Population',
                'value' => function($model){
                    return Yii::$app->formatter->asInteger($model->population); //Output 1,000
                },
            ],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]);
    ?>
```

**Update:** Like was mentioned in comments, You can also use this two technics to format the value:

```
//Gridview
....
[
    'attribute' => 'population',
    'format' => 'integer',
],
....
```

and/or:

```
//Gridview
....
'population:integer',
....
```

Comment: First of all thanks for you answer.
One more question, how does your solution works regarding localizaton ?
Let's say that in one particular country they use another kind of sign for thousandSeparator, in you way I'm basically hard coding the  ' , ' as separator.

Is there a prebuild function that can modify his behavior according to the language/country ?

Comment: @Pickeroll the formatter uses intl library to format the numbers. [See documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-formatting#localizing-data-format) for more details. If you want some non-standard separators you have to implement the logic that would take care of setting the separators.

Comment: There is no need to use `value` callback for calling formatter. If you use `'format' => 'integer'` it will do the same thing. Or you can use the short syntax and define column as `'population:integer'`. Also you have a typo in `'attribite' => 'population'` it should be `attribute`.